# Play sound only on the first pass in Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, audio

I have an As3 simple game with navigation buttons. It starts off with short intro with sound. When the game loads and the player dies it goes to retry screen with button which when is pressed goes back to the game. The problem is that when that happens flash plays the music from the short intro when returning to the game. How Do I stop this from happening. Currently I have no code for the sound. I just added the music directly to the frame with the intro and that's it. So what code do I write for the sound to execute only once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I googled 'as3 load sound' and this popped up

http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3sound/

This will show you how to do it if the sound is in your library or if it's external.

With your audio file in the library right click on it and in properties>actionscript check export for actionscript and give it a class name yourAudioFileName

...then the code to start and stop will be

```
var mySound:Sound = new yourAudioFileName();
var myChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
// start it with
myChannel = mySound.play();
// stop it with
myChannel.stop();
```

Comment: Thank you. This really helped. I had read the material in that link, but it was confusing to me, because the code there always includes a URL link, and I could not separate that from the actual code. Anyway Thanks!